# What is sid claim in logout token in OpenID Connect Back-channel logout?

Tags: openid-connect

I'm currently working on a project related with OpenID Connect Back-channel logout. I need to include sid as a claim in the logout token as mentioned in the [specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html#LogoutToken).

> sid-
>   OPTIONAL. Session ID - String identifier for a Session. This represents a Session of a User Agent or device for a logged-in End-User at an RP. Different sid values are used to identify distinct sessions at an OP. The sid value need only be unique in the context of a particular issuer. Its contents are opaque to the RP. Its syntax is the same as an OAuth 2.0 Client Identifier.

From the explanation for sid, I have some confusions whether it tells about the session-id of the end-user at RP or about the session-id of the RP at OP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SID = unique identifier of session of end user on a particular device/user agent, etc.
Suppose that I logged-in from android phone in game app and game app uses openID and authenticates with either Facebook or Google. Game app launches the user agent and connects to OpenID provider. Here authentication happens and app gets the ID token (which contains the SID). Game app requests the User claims from OpenID provider and then creates a session on the device but sends the user information to create the session on game app server(RP here) as well.

Now suppose I logged into another app on same phone or different phone and did exactly the same thing. I am now logged into two different apps which has their own sessions but I will be having two session at OP. How will OP distinguish which session to kill. If no SID is there, it will kill all sessions and SID is there, only that session can be killed.

This is the simplest explanation I can give. Everything else is just how this is achieved.

Comment: Does OP create the SID and send that in ID token?

Comment: OP initiated logout (In SAML terms, it is called IDP initiated logout ) : In case of OpenID back channel logout, SID is generated by OP and also stored on OP side, In this case when RP gets the ID token from OP, it MUST get the SID in that token as well from OP. Now when RP receives the request for logout from OP (since OP knows when this token session is going to expire), it uses that SID to invalidate it's session. Here the complete session lifecycle of session is on OP side, there is a RP initiated one too, that is covered in http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!